# Prevent a view from appearing after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I added a constraint layout above another constraint layout and inside of it there is a button when I click on it it should make the constraint layout and the button disappear 
and this is the code

```
    Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout_inside);
        button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

the problem when I rotate the screen the constraint layout appears again 
how to prevent that?

Comment: See [Handling Configuration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be handled automatically, because the activity is being destroyed and created after orientation change. Thus, you have to handle it on your own.

Saving current state in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putBoolean("someKey", constraintLayout.visibility == View.VISIBLE)        
    }
```

Then, in `onCreate()`:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize views
        ...

        // if `savedInstanceState` is not null, then look for `someKey` in bundle
        savedInstanceState?.run {
            val isVisible = getBoolean("someKey")
            constraintLayout.visibility = if (isVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
        } 

        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
          // This activity is starting for the first time, 
          // not an orientation change case
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this method to your Activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.lanscape_activity);
        // your own layout

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.portrait_activity);
        // your own layout
    }
}
```

And this line in your Manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```